# get path2D from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

How can I get the path2D after the canvas has done its calculations?

```
ctx.resetTransform()
ctx.translate(2, 2)
ctx.scale(2, 2)
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(30, 50)
ctx.lineTo(150, 100)
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
ctx.stroke()
ctx.closePath()

//get path2D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The context's *current default path* is an opaque and internal object. We can't access it by scripts, and we can't read anything from it.
What you could do, is to use a `Path2D` object directly.
To make use of the context current transform like you did in OP, you can use a DOMMatrix object, and the `Path2D#addPath(path, matrix)` method, which will apply the matrix on the added path:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mat = new DOMMatrix()
  .translate(2, 2)
  .scale(2, 2);
const p1 = new Path2D();
p1.moveTo(30, 50);
p1.lineTo(150, 100);
const p2 = new Path2D();
p2.addPath(p1, mat);
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.stroke(p2);
```

```html
<canvas height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Note yhat Path2D is also an opaque object (currently), and we can't read anything from it either. If this is what you want (e.g get back the segments, or an SVG path definition, then I invite you to try my [Path2d inspection prototype.](https://github.com/Kaiido/path2D-inspection)